# Oshin like html template

Tags: html, css, themes

I need to work on a similar design as is used in this website http://www.zaman.ae/, They are  using `Oshin` template which unfortunately is only available for word press plugin only, how can i create something similar in design as is used for this website.

Any pointer would be of great help or a similar template which i can use for HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. [Find a structure-similar](http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress) template for wordpress and edit it
       to ressemble zaman's layout.
2. Create your own wordpress template.